# Creating Google Friendly Folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dynamic, seo

Basically I'm trying to figure out a way to make

http://www.mysite.com/check/google.com

show the contents of the page

http://www.mysite.com/check.php?site=test.com

and I want users to think that the actual URL is  http://www.mysite.com/check/google.com instead of the long one.

But I need to do this in the friendliest way for Google so that they aren't looking at it as a redirect and it'll still rank well...  Any help will be greatly appreciated if you can post some sample code... Thanks!

Comment: what's google.com at the end of url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, try adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?check/(.*)$ /check.php?site=$1 [L]
```